# Can Apex method be called from <apex:commandButton> oncomplete attribute?

Tags: apex, commandbutton

**Visualforce Page:**
                                                                                                                         


I'm calling an apex method 'removeServiceTechnician' in oncomplete attribute. Is it possible to call a method in oncomplete attribute. It's throwing an error. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You can call actionfunction in onComplete. Through actionfunction call apex method.

Comment: @user42000 call actionFunction through `oncomplete` and eventually invoke `action` method

Comment: Can we have two actionFunction in one VF page, because already i'm having one actionFunction in my page

Comment: As long as your actionFunction name is unique, its should be fine. There is no limitation on a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible, call `apex:actionFunction` from your `apex:commandButton`'s oncomplete, which calls your controller method.

Also, there is no limitation on use of `apex:actionfunction`'s, note that its name should be unique

Comment: Your answer is somewhat like comments which are already there.

Comment: Agreed, no offence, but I was on typing from mobile and I think we all posted at almost same time. Had given +1 to both your comments when I noticed them. Keep up the good work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible using actionFunction that needs to be called from commandButton's oncomplete event. Below is the sample code.

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!controllerMethod1}" rerender="none" oncomplete="onCompleteJSFunc();" />  
    <apex:actionFunction name="actionFunctionJS" action="{!controllerMethod2}" reRender="someDiv" />
</apex:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onCompleteJSFunc(){
        actionFunctionJS();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't even need the javascript, just call actionFuctionJS();  on the `oncomple` attribute

Comment: onCompleteJSFunc(); is not being called

Comment: Its called on oncomplete event on commandButton.